# Execute onclick before input

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

This is difficult to approach because I'm running "Custom javascript for websites 2" Chrome extension. So **I can't modify the code**, only I can add.

The webpage have a form which it's loaded doing an ajax request. Then, there is a button without form validation. **I want to add form validation**.

The default form submits the form with a onclick HTML attribute inside an input.

1- First failed approach:

```
document.getElementById('submit-btn').onclick = myValidation;
```

Result: it works the first time I press the button. But the second time, submits as default.

2- Second failed approach:

```
document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener('click', myValidation, true);
```

Result: first do the default submit (onclick attribute) and then, do myValidation function. I thought what putting addEventListener true argument, I will fire first. But not.

Is there a way for do that?

Answer (score 0):

in first case you should path reference to function NOT the function execute result

**INCORRECT:**

```
document.getElementById('submit-btn').onclick = myValidation();
```

**CORRECT:**

```
document.getElementById('submit-btn').onclick = myValidation;
```

Comment: Sorry for that, it was a mistake while writing the answer, I'm learning javascript.